# How to sample colors outside Photoshop CC, using Color Picker, on Windows 10

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've always used the Color Picker to sample colors outside of Photoshop, by clicking on the image and then dragging to wherever the desired color was on the screen.

Now, with CC and Windows 10 (as of 6/6/16) that is not possible. Anything outside the Photoshop window is sampled as black.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: perhaps screenshot the image you want to sample, paste into photoshop and sample the colour from there?

Comment: Color Picker is not a brand, it is a concept. so Try another aplication, there are several free.

Comment: this is the first link that comes up when I google "sample colors outside window photoshop".  So even though it may be off topic and the answer might now work for his specific scenario, it's really helping idiots like me searching for answers.

Answer (score 2):

To sample colors outside the Photoshop window, try the following:

1. Click and hold the mouse button down somewhere in Photoshop window
2. Move the eyedropper to where you want
3. You will see the color of the foreground patch change as you move your cursor over different areas with different colors
4. Let go of the mouse button the pick the color under the cursor

Comment: this works for me